# PXE boot to diskless thin client

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, pxe-boot, thin-client

I am trying to revive a school's computer lab. The lab's original sponsors discontinued their services and donated all the hardware to the school. The original setup was done on Ubuntu server that hosted 20 thin clients to also run Ubuntu.

- I was able to start up the original config, but with limited
  stability. They asked me to rather loot to a Windows solution. So My
  current setup is using Windows 2012 R2 data-center as the server and
  CCBoot as my PXE host.(hardware summery at end)
- I was able to get the client to boot up to the windows loading
  screen, but then it either freeze or blue screen. I wanted to use
  windows xp embedded for the client OS however I am unable to legally
  obtain a copy of it. So My options are Windows 7(ultimate and
  embedded), Windows 8(Pro and embedded).
  Server:
- DELL PowerEdge R200
- Single socket Server Mobo
- 2 Lan ports
- Core2Duo 2.6Ghz

Thin Client:

- WYSE VXO
- 512MB Ram

Running tests, I was unable to boot anything up properly with different hardware setups. I used My own server running AMD PhenomII x6 with 16GB ram and an SSD but I still cant't get it to boot. I went over to use a Dell Latitude E4200 laptop with 2GB Ram as the client but that still made no difference.

While running the tests however I noticed that when the boot sequence starts the network activity would go up and transfer 45.2MB(Windows 7) 56.7MB(Windows 8) and then stop. This is the same consistently.

Answer (score 1):

This Wyse is a linux integrated. They are linux ready and I seen some guide to install a linux onto them, but it's not a supported path. Its why your PXE boot work well in my opinion. The minimum memory required for Windows 7 & + is 1 Gig, so the Wyse don't meet the minimum spec.

RDP to a session from the Wyse directly to a RDS server would be a better idea, as each user will have more CPU and RAM to open their application. Making a seemless connect via the .ini would be easy.

In that plan, if a Wyse broke and you replace it with a new's one, the RDP will still work and the. ini too. (more scalable)

Answer (score -2):

Looks like problem of image.
Please check your process when you transfer your image to server.

1. make image for your clients
2. try to install software for network boot as ccboot client
3. transfer your windows environment to server
4. network boot

Windows 7 is strict to their hard disk signature. that's why when you finish transfer your environment, you should uninstall hard disk from master client. But if you install to server directly, don't need to uninstall. just check your step carefully first.

If you want test other solution, just try other solution.. like XENIT.
They make their solution on UBUNTU. You can download 5 free license of XENIT.